# What does "zurusona" mean?

Tags: words, rōmaji

Miyabe Kingo wrote in an English-language letter the phrase “a sharp zurusona wife” to describe the woman whose house he boarded at. "Zurusona" seems to be the insertion of a Japanese word written in romaji into his otherwise English sentence, which he felt best described her to the Japanese reader rather than writing a fully English description. What does it mean?

I tried looking it up under these spellings ずるそな、ずるそうな、 even づるそな、づるそうな but the only thing I found was 狡(ずる＝cunning deed; sneaky person). Can 狡 be turned into a form that might be romanized as "zurusona"?

Comment: 「ずるそうな」 is three words -- 「ずる + そう + な」.  Of course, it will not be listed in a dictionary.  It should not be; It is a whole phrase.

Comment: ずる(stem of the i-adjective [ずるい](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/120523/m0u/)) + そうな(連体形 of the auxiliary [そうだ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/129024/m0u/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

狡{ずる}い = "sly / dishonest / sneaky." And 狡{ずる}そうな = "looks sly / dishonest / sneaky."

Does this help?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any idea of why the dictionaries couldn't pull that up by typing in ずるそうな or zurusouna? They only pulled up 狡, 狡い, and ズルズル

Comment: Well, I don't know what dictionaries you have looked up, but my impression is many Japanese dictionaries are content themselves with merely listing words as they are together with some synonyms, and don't care about explaining the usage. Thus.they can serve hardly more than thesauri.

Comment: May I as which online dictionaries you use and/or which most Japanese use? Maybe I am not using the best ones.

Comment: I am sorry I can't recommend one as I seldom use Japanese-English or English-Japanese dictionaries. You may want "googling" with "good Japanese-English/English-Japanese dictionaries" as the keyword. As for Japanese dictionaries written for the Japanese, this one -> dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/dicts/ja/smk_kok7 is a good choice as pocket dictionary, and this one .= daijirin.dual-d.net and this one -> fuzambo.net/jisho0.html are good candidtaes for more extensive ones. I've been told that this one -> nikkoku.net/introduction/index.html is excellent, but I can't judge as I have never used it.

Comment: [ずるそうな on 英辞郎](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA) と、 [ずるそうな on Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%22)

Comment: The reason why you can't find ずるそうな in dictionaries is the same reason why you can't find "sly-looking" as a separate entry in English dictionaries.

Comment: @Choko Thank you for finding ずるそうな in some online Japanese/English dictionaries! I often use 英辞郎 but I shall start using Weblio as well.